# PVector Heading() for 3D Rotation

Tags: java, vector, rotation, coordinates, processing

I want to use the heading() function in the PVector class, but I am using P3D and have an x,y,and z for my PVector.  How would I re-write this function to allow it to work for 3D space?  My goal is to do something like:

```
      size(100, 100, P3D);
      PVector v = new PVector(.2, .11, .54);
      rotate( v.heading() ); //set rotation from PVector named v
      line(0, 0, 10, 0); //draw line that will be rotated in correct direction
```

The above code doesn't display the correct rotation in 3D space since v.heading() is only suited for 2D coordinate space. How can I achieve this using rotateX(), rotateY(), rotateZ()?  I'd like to avoid using a quaternion if possible and use the rotate functions.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

Using the `heading()` function in 2D is transforming 2D Cartesian coordinates (x,y) into 2D polar coordinates (radius, angle). A 3D version of polar coordinates is [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system):

[image: spherical coordinates example]

The 3D point `P` can be represented as three linear coordinates (x,y,z) or one linear coordinate and two angles (rho, theta, phi). Rho is the length of the vector, theta is the angle in the x-y plane, and phi is the angle in the angle into the z plane. These equations describe the conversion:

`rho = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`

`phi = arccos(z/rho)`

`theta = arctan(y/x)`

You should be able to use the rotateX(), etc functions using these angles. Note that this uses the mathematics convention for the angle names theta and phi; in physics, these labels are reversed from what's shown above.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Kevinsa5.  Could you point me to how I would use this in rotateX(), rotateY() and rotateZ() to achieve the correct rotation using these variables.

Comment: I've tried this with no luck:
    rotateX( sin(theta) * cos(theta) );
    rotateY( cos(theta) );
    rotateZ( sin(theta) * sin(theta) );

Comment: ...as well as: rotateX( rho * sin(phi) * cos(theta) ); rotateY( rho*sin(phi) * sin(theta) ); rotateZ( rho*cos(phi) );

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is supposed to represent. `sin(theta)*cos(theta)` doesn't seem like a useful thing, and it won't be an angle, anyway. The `rotateX(angle)` function rotates around the x-axis, and the same for the other axes-- pass it an angle, not whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

What kevinsa5 said, except use the inverse sine function to get the elevation.  Use the atan2 function for the azimuth (or better, simply use the vector's 2D heading method).  And use the vector's mag method for its magnitude.

```
rho = v.mag();

phi = asin(v.z/rho);

theta = atan2(v.y, v.x);
```

Working backwards, think "X - Y - Z" and try:

```
PVector p = new PVector(v.mag(), 0, 0); // X

rotateY3D(p, phi); // Y

rotateZ3D(p, theta); // Z
```

Then compare p with the original v.